# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

I was looking everywhere but I couldn't find any solution for this error.

I'm using ExoPlayer for live video streaming. And my app crashes every time when I run it. If you can help me I will be happy.

I guess it should be somewhere in the XML file but I can't understand what means all that error. 
XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.devbrackets.android.exomedia.ui.widget.VideoView
    android:id="@+id/video_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:useDefaultControls="true"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity file:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();

    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("Here's path"));
    videoView.start();

    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
Process: rusiptv.net, PID: 25782
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{rusiptv.net/rusiptv.net.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.devbrackets.android.exomedia.ui.widget.VideoView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.devbrackets.android.exomedia.ui.widget.VideoView
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.devbrackets.android.exomedia.ui.widget.VideoView
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at rusiptv.net.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

If you can please explain to me more detailed about this error because if I will face this problem again then I can fix it easily.

Edit:
Guys thank you, everyone! I fixed this problem.

Solutions:

- `VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.video_view);`
- And I changed path for VideoView according to my packageName.

Comment: you should findViewById before using it (`VideoView`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check whether

```
<com.devbrackets.android.exomedia.ui.widget.VideoView
android:id="@+id/video_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:useDefaultControls="true"/>
```

path for VideoView is correct according to your packageName.

Comment: How I can check whether path for VideoView is correct according to your packageName?

Comment: Do you have VideoView as java class in your project ?

Comment: Yes I have VideoView

Comment: Now what is the package name at the top  in that class?

Comment: package="rusiptv.net">

Comment: then how can you find **com.devbrackets.android.exomedia.ui.widget.VideoView** in xml? you need to provide your package name like **rusiptv.net.VideoView**

Comment: Also make sure that **rusiptv.net** this package name is proper path for VideoView class. there is not any sub package for VideoView class

Comment: So I need to write **package="rusiptv.net.VideoView">** instead of **package="rusiptv.net">** in AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: No No you have to write **rusiptv.net.VideoView** instead of **com.devbrackets.android.exomedia.ui.widget.VideoView** in xml

Comment: Your customized View need to be provided with proper path in XML in order to find by Java class

Comment: Check package name from VideoView class not from manifest file

Comment: I'm so stupid.... How I can check package name from VideoView class?

Answer (score 0):

As i check this file is not complete implement according to user's feedback please try another video view  like this

```
 <VideoView 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:id="@+id/VideoView" />
```

Comment: But I'm using ExoPlayer and I need exactly that VideoView from ExoPlayer's library

Answer (score 0):

You Must override the constructor

```
public VideoPlayerView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
super(context, attributeSet);
}
```

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you add the library dependency and must be added this line

```
VideoView vedioView = findViewById(R.id.video_view);
```

Before use **vedioView**. I think it will solve your problem

Comment: `VideoView vedioView = findViewById(R.id.video_view); `
Do you add this line